# Unable to enterprise install app on iPad...could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, installation

i have created an app which I am hoping to distribute wirelessly, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

I have followed all steps on this page, uploaded the files to our server and accessed on a couple of iPads, so the pop up displays " would like to install ." I click 'Install' and the apps icon appears on the iPad, the waiting bar appears followed by 'Installing' Perfect I thought... but no, the download gets to about 50-75% through and then an error message pops up, "Unable to Download Application,  could not be installed at this time."

At first I thought this was caused by our weak internet connection, and then I thought maybe it was the app size, however when building in xcode on the same iPad it all works fine so this cant be the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this? and/or know what the problem may be.... really hit a wall here.

http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/1952/20130226160335.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made sure you fully match the requirements on http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/?lang=en-us#app43ad871e? For example, MIME types for the server?

Comment: Hi thanks for this I've just added the correct MIME types to the server as per the link but still nothing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but connect your iPad to your computer, and check the Console to see if anything is reported when the download fails. If you notice anything relevant, append it to your Question.